# Oracle sql replace multiple special character with another in single query

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

How can I replace a particular special character with another character?

Eg. In the sentence `I want to replace à with a and è with e` I want to replace **à** with **a** and **è** with **e** both in same query.

If I use replace simply it doesn't work in SQL Developer 21.2.

Oraccle database: 12 c

I took dump of the problem character:

select dump('é', 1016) from dual

Result:

Typ=96 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,a9

Comment: Show us your SQL.

Comment: "Doesn't work" provides absolutely no information about your real issue. Please clarify what it means and provide error codes/messages or result you want and result you get along with your current code.

Answer (score 2):

Just try one of these ways:

1. Solution 1:

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE('I want to replace à with a and è with e', 'à', 'a'),'è', 'e') FROM DUAL;
```

2. Solution 2:

```
SELECT translate('I want to replace à with a and è with e', 'àè', 'ae') FROM DUAL;
```

the second looks like better.

I use Oracle 12C release 2.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Sql developer version is 21.2, could this be environment issue?

Comment: Well, it might be, I tested this in Oracle 21c as well. What error are you getting @Velocity ?

Comment: No error. It just doesn't  replace. No change after running the query.

Comment: @Velocity: You are saying that both queries return the original string `I want to replace à with a and è with e`? That is hard to believe. I tried this with Oracle 11.2, and it worked. I tried this with SQL Developer 22.2, and it worked. It is very unlikely that some older Oracle version fails with these simple queries. And it is very unlikely that some older SQL Developer version somehow prevents Oracle from returning the proper result. Have you tried exact the two queries that Reza is showing?

Comment: yes, i used exct query.

Comment: @Velocity the result does not depend on sql developer version.
for test, run the queries by using other characters. for example replace a with g in the sentence. does it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using TRANSLATE() function like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` function can do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE( 'I want to replace à with a', 'à', 'a') FROM DUAL;
```

[sql editor online](https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle19hr/a52ea1dae77718359c5f2a1048c86c00/)